# OS X shared internet and local file sharing

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, internet-sharing, afp

Is there any way to still do Airdrop and AFP/SSH when I'm sharing my iMac's internet (ethernet) connection over WiFi to my MacBookPro?

I tried to find my iMac and vice versa in the LAN but they're totally invisible for each other.

I'm using BackToMyMac now, but it's awfully slow due to NAT problems. Sadly I can't adjust my main router, as it's managed by my landlord's IT manager and they won't change settings.